# C++ structure 2D string member initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, string, initialization, structure

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct letter
{
    string lines[5];
}s[26];

int main()
{
    //struct letter s[25];
    s[0].lines =      // error while initializing here
    {
        "..*..",
        ".*.*.",
        ".***.",
        ".*.*.",
        ".*.*."
    };

    s[1].lines[5] =   // also if I do this
    {
        ".**..",
        ".*.*.",
        ".***.",
        ".*.*.",
        ".**.."
    };

  return 0;
}
```

**Check here :** [**Ideone Link**](http://ideone.com/04V8VZ)

I can't figure out what is wrong with this code.
I tried many ways. I even changed the structure member to 2d char array but getting same issue.Please do some help!

**Compilation Info :**

prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
error: expected ';' before '{' token
error: expected primary-expression before '{' token
error: expected ';' before '{' token

Comment: I am facing the issue just from start of main fucntion. Error while initializing the structure string.

Comment: Initializer list of array is only valid when you do declaration and definition of the array in the same line, like `string s[2]={"a","b"}`

Comment: @texasbruce : Please check before you confirm anything! :)

Comment: @user3507787: He's correct: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ed67c97f558fc56.  The key part is actually that arrays cannot be copied via `operator=`.

Comment: @MooingDuck : I have put two versions of block to show the difference. I know it can't be assigned. Check the second type of assignment for s[1].

Comment: @user3507787: I ignored that one because that isn't even semantically correct.  It's even more wrong than the first one.

Comment: @user3507787 Yes I do. And the same to you.

Comment: and a workaround is to use C++11 generalized initializer list, and it works on all stl assignment operator(but still not built-in array or std::array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The way you are initializing the `s[26]` array is suitable only at declaration.**

Here is how you can do it in your code:

```
struct letter
{
    string lines[5];
};

letter s[26] =
{
    {
        "..*..",
        ".*.*.",
        ".***.",
        ".*.*.",
        ".*.*."
    },
    {
        ".**..",
        ".*.*.",
        ".***.",
        ".*.*.",
        ".**.."
    }
};
```

Or even better, if you don't really need the `letter` structure:

```
string letter[26][5] =
{
    {
        "..*..",
        ".*.*.",
        ".***.",
        ".*.*.",
        ".*.*."
    },
    {
        ".**..",
        ".*.*.",
        ".***.",
        ".*.*.",
        ".**.."
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I would like to upvote but I don't have even 15 points. Well I like the strategies but this doesn't completes the answer as a whole :)

Comment: @user3507787: Why not? The question states "what is wrong with this code". The answer states "Initialize your arrays at declaration", which implies that this code is wrong because you are initializing your arrays **after** declaration. The answer also shows you how to do it, and in addition, suggests a simplified version that might be suitable for your needs. So I would say it is a pretty complete response for your question.

Comment: @barakmanos: I don't see "what is wrong with this code", but I do see "I can't figure out what is wrong with this code.". I think the answer would be improved by mentioning _why_ his code failed.

Comment: @barakmanos: (1) you can't meant "definition" not "declaration". (2) You can only initialize _anything_ at definition. (3) You can assign to arrays at other times if they're members, and a couple other weird situations.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: 1. I actually **did** mean declaration. 2. I did realize that the statement "You can only initialize an array at declaration" was semantically incorrect, as I referred to the specific way in which OP is initializing the array (answer revised on that).

Comment: @barakmanos: (1) GCC and I beg to differ: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81199b56d51a02bc

Comment: I don't know why but I'm not satisfied! We can assign any attribute of struct a it's value by doing something like s[0].data=10. So why not with this one?

Comment: @user3507787: Arrays are not copiable with `operator=`

Comment: @MooingDuck : What do you mean?  string s[]={"a","b"} or int a[2][2]={{2,3},{3,4}} are not valid?

Comment: @user3507787: Due to a quirk in the language, those are actually _constructors_, not _copies_.  Which is why they work for arrays.

Comment: @MoingDuck : I'm not getting you at all. C doesn't has concept of Constructors at least :|

Comment: @user3507787: Your use of `iostream` and `string` suggests that it is C++, **not** C.

Comment: Ok, I rate you best as nobody is answering this! :)